# Zoom—One participant can't hear 2 others (in a 33 person meeting)

Tags: zoom-meeting

As the title says, I'm in a meeting with 33 participants, and one specific person can't hear two other (specific) people. He can hear anyone else, just not those two. The rest of us can all hear those two fine.

Details that might help

- The one participant is using his iPad
- The two that he can't hear (but everyone else can) happen to be the hosts of the meeting

Any ideas what's going on here? Seems like a very bizarre problem to me.

Comment: Have the three people update Zoom (there is a very recent update), restart their computers and check.

Comment: How about you check with the zoom support, since it has become famous during the pandemic, chances are that it has some bugs in it.